# How to retrieve corrupted block from NAND dump?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, ubifs

I have a corrupted ubifs partition:

```
[   16.594177] UBIFS: recovery needed
[   16.708496] UBIFS error (pid 845): ubifs_check_node: bad CRC: calculated 0x60deed4b, read 0x8709e701
[   16.718170] UBIFS error (pid 845): ubifs_check_node: bad node at LEB 150:50696
[   16.725830] UBIFS error (pid 845): ubifs_scanned_corruption: corruption at LEB 150:50696
[   16.743072] UBIFS error (pid 845): ubifs_recover_leb: LEB 150 scanning failed
```

i have dumped related mtd with nanddump utils, how can i find which PEB is related to corrupted LEB?